# React Native/Expo Items within horizontal Flatlist have different dimensions

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to create a horizontal flatlist and within it, have multiple components called InstructionCards. I would also like to have them fill up more of the red spacing. However, this results in some of the items being differently sized from one another. Below are my code:

Page with Flatlist:

```
import { Text, View,Pressable, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Link } from 'expo-router';
import InstructionCard from '../../../components/InstructionCard';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';


const Routine = () => {
    const TestData = [
        {
            id: '1',
            stepNum: 1,
            duration: 6,
            specialText: 'testing',
            brush: 'brush test'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            stepNum: 2,
            duration: 8,
            specialText: 'random special text 1',
            brush: 'brush A'
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            stepNum: 3,
            duration: 10,
            specialText: 'special message here',
            brush: 'brush C'
        },
        {
            id: '4',
            stepNum: 4,
            duration: 12,
            specialText: 'something unique',
            brush: 'brush D'
        }
    ];

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            {/* asChild passes down props to pressable */}
            {/* <Link href="/" asChild>
                <Pressable>
                    <Text>Routine</Text>
                </Pressable>
            </Link> */}
            
            <View style={styles.model}>
                <Text>Model</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.animation}>
                <Text>Animation</Text>
            </View>
            

            {/* <View style={styles.instructionstest}>
                <InstructionCard
                    stepNum={1}
                    specialText='testing'
                    brush='brush test'
                    duration={6}
                />

                
            </View> */}


            <FlatList
                
                
                contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: "stretch", flex: 1}}
                
                data={TestData}
                renderItem={({item}) => 
                    <InstructionCard 
                        stepNum={item.stepNum}
                        specialText={item.specialText}
                        brush={item.brush}
                        duration={item.duration}
                        
                    />
                }
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                horizontal
                // disableIntervalMomentum
                pagingEnabled
                // centerContent
                // scrollEnabled={false}
                
                snapToAlignment='start'
                // contentContainerStyle={styles.instructions}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        // gap: 10,
        // alignItems: 'center',
        // justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    model: {
        flex: 2,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
        
    },
    animation: {
        flex: 2,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        
    },
    instructions: {
        // flex: 5,
        // flexGrow: 0,
        // flex: 1,
        // height: "100%",
        // justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        height: "auto"
    },


})

export default Routine;
```

Instruction Card component:

```
import {Text, StyleSheet, View, Pressable, useWindowDimensions} from 'react-native'
import { useFonts, Inter_600SemiBold, Inter_400Regular, Inter_700Bold } from '@expo-google-fonts/inter'
import { MaterialCommunityIcons, MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import BrushIcon from '../assets/svg/icon.svg';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
import useTimer from './hooks/useTimer';
import {CountdownCircleTimer} from 'react-native-countdown-circle-timer'

interface InstructionCardProps {
    stepNum: number,
    specialText: string,
    brush: string,
    duration: number
}

const InstructionCard: React.FC<InstructionCardProps> = ({stepNum, specialText, brush, duration}) => {
    const [fontsLoaded, fontsError] = useFonts({
        Inter_600SemiBold,
        Inter_400Regular,
        Inter_700Bold,
    })

    const {height, width} = useWindowDimensions();

    // const {secondsLeft, startTimer} = useTimer();

    if (!fontsLoaded && !fontsError) {return null}
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
            <View style={[styles.group, {flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between'}]}>
                <Text style={[styles.fontBold]}>Step {stepNum}</Text>

                <CountdownCircleTimer
                    isPlaying={true}
                    duration={duration}
                    colors={'#0064FF'}
                    size={width/10}
                    strokeWidth={width/75}
                    trailColor='#ffffff'
                    strokeLinecap='butt'
                />
            </View>
            

            <View style={[styles.group]}>
                <MaterialIcons name="info-outline" size={30} color="black" />
                {/* Needs to be able to wrap */}
                <Text style={styles.fontRegular}>{specialText}</Text> 
            </View>

            <View style={[styles.group]}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="toothbrush" size={30} color="black" />
                <Text style={styles.fontRegular}>{brush}</Text>

                {/* <Pressable onPress={()=>startTimer(duration)}>
                    <Text> Press to test</Text>
                </Pressable> */}
            </View>

        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cardContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#CEE2FF',
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 20,
        shadowColor: 'black',
        shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 2},
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 2,
        
    },
    fontBold: {
        fontFamily: 'Inter_700Bold',
        fontSize: 23
    },
    fontRegular: {
        fontFamily: 'Inter_400Regular',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    group: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        gap: 15,
        flex: 2,
    }
})

export default InstructionCard
```

This is how it currently looks like:

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I893R.png)

This is how i want it to look like:

[Actual Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDfVt.png)

I tried adding flex to the items itself but it seems like it would happen when the FlatList is horizontal

Comment: It would be more suitable if you add **horizontal** to your question title. I couldn't add edits. e.g: _How to Ensure Equal Height for Horizontal FlatList Items in React Native_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Efficient but static

Page with FlatList:

```js
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={{ height: someFixHeight }}
  // ...
/>;
```

Instruction Card component:

```js
cardContainer: {
    height: "100%",
    // ...
  },
```

### Costly but dynamic

Page with FlatList:

```js
  const [itemExtraStyle, setItemExtraStyle] = React.useState(null);
  // ...
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {/* ... */}
      <FlatList
        onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) =>
          setItemExtraStyle({ height: nativeEvent.layout.height })
        }
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <InstructionCard
            // ...
            style={itemExtraStyle}
          />
        )}
        // ...
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

Instruction Card component:

```js
 <View style={[styles.cardContainer, style]}>
```